# Find Value that Partitions two Numpy Arrays Equally

Tags: python, numpy, partitioning

I have two arrays (`x1` and `x2`) of equal length that have overlapping ranges of values.

I need to find a value `q` such that `l1-l2` is minimized, and

```
l1 = x1[np.where(x1 > q)].shape[0]
l2 = x2[np.where(x2 < q)].shape[0]
```

I need this to be reasonably high-performance since the arrays can be large. A solution using native numpy routines would be preferred.

Comment: `l1` and `l2` has to be the same size?

Comment: Or as close to the same value as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may have found a fairly simple way to do it.

```
x1 = (50 - 10) * np.random.random(10000) + 10
x2 = (75 - 25) * np.random.random(10000) + 25

x1.sort()
x2.sort()
x2 = x2[::-1] # reverse the array

# The overlap point should fall where the difference is smallest
diff = np.abs(x1 - x2)

# get the index of where the minimum occurs
loc = np.where(diff == np.min(diff))

q1 = x1[loc]    # 38.79087351
q2 = x2[loc]    # 38.79110941
```

M4rtini's solution produces `q = 38.7867527`.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a smarter way to look for a value, but you can do an exhaustive search as follows:

```
>>> x1 = np.random.rand(10)
>>> x2 = np.random.rand(10)
>>> x1.sort()
>>> x2.sort()
>>> x1
array([ 0.12568451,  0.30256769,  0.33478133,  0.41973331,  0.46493576,
        0.52173197,  0.72289189,  0.72834444,  0.78662283,  0.78796277])
>>> x2
array([ 0.05513774,  0.21567893,  0.29953634,  0.37426842,  0.40000622,
        0.54602497,  0.7225469 ,  0.80116148,  0.82542633,  0.86736597])
```

We can compute `l1` if `q` is one of the items in `x1` as:

```
>>> l1_x1 = len(x1) - np.arange(len(x1)) - 1
>>> l1_x1
array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

And `l2` for the same `q` as:

```
>>> l2_x1 = np.searchsorted(x1, x2)
>>> l2_x1
array([ 0,  1,  1,  3,  3,  6,  6, 10, 10, 10], dtype=int64)
```

You can similarly get values for `l1` and `l2` when `q` is in `x2`:

```
>>> l2_x2 = np.arange(len(x2))
>>> l2_x2
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> l1_x2 = len(x1) - np.searchsorted(x1, x2, side='right')
>>> l1_x2
array([10,  9,  9,  7,  7,  4,  4,  0,  0,  0], dtype=int64)
```

And you then simply check for the minimum of `l1 - l2`:

```
>>> np.concatenate((l1_x1 - l2_x1, l1_x2 - l2_x2))
array([  9,   7,   6,   3,   2,  -2,  -3,  -8,  -9, -10,  10,   8,   7,
         4,   3,  -1,  -2,  -7,  -8,  -9], dtype=int64)
>>> q_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(np.concatenate((l1_x1 - l2_x1, l1_x2 - l2_x2))))
>>> q = x1[q_idx]  if q_idx < len(x1) else x2[q_idx - len(x1)]
>>> q
0.54602497466094291
>>> x1[x1 > q].shape[0]
4L
>>> x2[x2 < q].shape[0]
5L
```

Answer (score 2):

This is fundamentally an interval problem so you might want to do some reading on [Interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), but you don't need to understand interval trees to solve this problem.

If you think of every `(x1[i], x2[i])` as being an interval, you're looking for the value `q` which splits the intervals into two groups as evenly as possible ignoring intervals that overlap `q`. Lets take the easy case first:

```
from numpy import array
x1 = array([19, 32, 47, 13, 56,  1, 87, 48])
x2 = array([44, 38, 50, 39, 85, 26, 92, 64])
x1sort = np.sort(x1)
x2sort = np.sort(x2)[::-1]
diff = abs(x2sort - x1sort)
mindiff = diff.argmin()
print mindiff, x2sort[mindiff], x1sort[mindiff]
# 4 44 47
```

[image]

@xvtk's solution works well in this case and gives us a range of [44, 47]. Because no intervals overlap the range, all values of `q` in the range are equivalent and yield an optimal result. Here is an example that is a little more tricky:

```
x1 = array([12, 65, 46, 81, 71, 77, 37])
x2 = array([ 20,  85,  59, 122, 101,  87,  58])
x1sort = np.sort(x1)
x2sort = np.sort(x2)[::-1]
diff = abs(x2sort - x1sort)
mindiff = diff.argmin()
print mindiff, x2sort[mindiff], x1sort[mindiff], x1sort[mindiff-1]
# 59 71 65
```

[image]

Here the solution gives us a range of [59, 71] but notice that not all values in the range are equivalent. Anything to the left of the green line will produce 3 and 4 intervals on the left and right respectively, while anything to the right of the green line will produce 3 intervals on both sides.

I'm pretty sure that the optimal solution is guaranteed to be in the range produced by @xvtk's solution. It's possible that one of the red lines is guaranteed to be an optimal solution, though I'm not sure on this point. Hope that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't it only make sense to consider these intervals after the arrays have been sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use some of the optimizing functions in scipy to minimize the difference.

Like this for example

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin 

def findQ(q, *x):
    x1, x2 = x
    l1 = x1[np.where(x1 > q)].shape[0]
    l2 = x2[np.where(x2 < q)].shape[0]

    return abs(l1-l2)

x1 = (50 - 10) * np.random.random(10000) + 10
x2 = (75 - 25) * np.random.random(10000) + 25

q0 =  (min(x2) + max(x1))/2.0 

q  = fmin(findQ, q0, (x1,x2))
```